# List prints two values instead of one

Tags: python, python-3.x, radix

I created a Decimal to Hexadecimal numeric translator which converts any decimal number to hexadecimal. I insert the remainder to the list that contains `['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F']`which is the quotient of number that I inserted divided by 16. When I print the `myResult = ""` as a storage of my process. It's giving me a two values.

```
changes = int(input("Choose one: "))

if changes == 1:
     myRemainder = 0
     myResult = ""

number = int(input("Enter a number: "))#74

while number > 0:
    myList = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F']

    myRemainder = number % 16
    #storage   #append remainder in list
    myResult = myList[myRemainder] + myResult
    number = number // 16

    print(myResult)
```

The first value is the result of the last process and the last value is the result of the whole process. Any help would appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put `print(myResult)` *in the loop*. So for a number like 74 it'll print the first digit, then print both digits.

Move the `print()` call out of the loop:

```
while number > 0:
    myList = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F']

    myRemainder = number % 16
    #storage   #append remainder in list
    myResult = myList[myRemainder] + myResult
    number = number // 16

print(myResult)
```

to only print the final result, not any intermediaries.

You can simplify your code some more; there is no need to re-create yoru `myList` list each and every iteration of your loop; you could even just make it a string. Next, use the [`divmod` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod) to produce both the result of the division and the remainder in one call:

```
digits = '0123456789ABCDEF'
while number:
    number, digit = divmod(number, 16)
    myResult = digits[digit] + myResult
```

Comment: @JonClements: one small step at a time. How about moving `myList` out of the loop too? Unfortunately, in a mobile network deadzone soon.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks helped me so much. This is much easier to read than calling division and modulo result :)